# animate single layer-list item in android

Tags: android, animation

I have a "layer-list" (rotated_image.xml) which is a "imageview" background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/shadow" />
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
        android:duration="5000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@drawable/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toDegrees="360" >
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/button" />
    </rotate>
</item>
```

1) I need to start and stop third image rotation on "imageview" click. I do not know how to get reference to my third item in layer-list and how to start animation?

2) I also need to put opacity to my second item in list, is it possible?

3) Can I combine one more animation here (fade in-fade out), I need it for my first item in list?

If my question is to complicated, can someone give me good reference or advice?

Thanks,
Milos